# CNAME causing "Server Not Found" with AWS S3

Tags: domain-name-system, cname-record, amazon-s3, slicehost

I have a goDaddy site with a CNAME record set up to look at a specific bucket in my S3 account. It works fine and loads files without problem.

I have a server with SliceHost that has a CNAME record ("static") set up exactly the same as the one at goDaddy (with the domain name changed appropriately). When I attempt to access a file at the subdomain, however, I get a "Server not found" error. If I try to access the bucket file directly, it works fine.

dig and nslookup reveal that the subdomain is, indeed, eventually pointing at Amazon.

Here is what the ANSWER section of dig looks like:

```
static.imdoingscience.com.  2201    IN  CNAME   static.imdoingscience.com.s3.amazonaws.com.
static.imdoingscience.com.s3.amazonaws.com. 60  IN  CNAME   s3-directional-w.amazonaws.com.
s3-directional-w.amazonaws.com. 39  IN  CNAME   s3-1-w.amazonaws.com.
s3-1-w.amazonaws.com.   59  IN  A   72.21.207.241
```

I don't know if it matters, but the non-working instance is Ubuntu Hardy LTS running nginx. I don't think it should since a CNAME record seems to be a redirect at the nameserver level (I'm only just getting into this stuff).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't get "server not found", I get an S3 error:

```
<Error>
  <Code>NoSuchBucket</Code>
  <Message>The specified bucket does not exist</Message>
  <BucketName>static.imdoingscience.com.</BucketName>
  <RequestId>F227137BF1862E64</RequestId>
  <HostId>
    ENl2Yp/hp++mXtTF9Zze5VX/+KN/zaYV+KeToMikX9JK/3oTK/k38URYisLmP2uF
  </HostId>
 </Error>
```

It looks to me like you need to talk to Amazon.

Comment: This works for me:
http://static.imdoingscience.com.s3.amazonaws.com/images/head.png

This was not:
http://static.imdoingscience.com/images/head.png

I did just check it again though, and it's suddenly working. Aren't CNAME entries supposed to be instantaneous? Why should it take 18 hours for it to start working? 

Does Amazon need a certain amount of time after the creation of a bucket for the webservice to begin working with it?

Comment: I've no idea - if it actually matters, you'd still need to talk to Amazon.

Comment: Just to clarify why I chose this as the answer: Amazon S3 apparently takes a while to setup a bucket for viewing.